# Installing virtualenv on a remote server in a local directory

Tags: python, django, directory, virtualenv, traceback

I have added the local directory to the path, untarred virtualenv 1.9.1, run the setup script with --prefix=$HOME/.local, but when I try to create a virtual environment I get an import error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./virtualenv", line 2, in ?
    import virtualenv
ImportError: No module named virtualenv
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh, and if it helps it is a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5

Comment: What version of python do you have?

Comment: well, the server runs 2.4, which I read is no longer supported by virtualenv, but I didn't think that mattered since virtualenv manages python versions.  I thought I would just be able to update python from within.  Have I misunderstood something fundamental?

Comment: Yes, `virtualenv` doesn't contain Python itself. It just creates a copy of the global installations(with custom options) into the virtual environment. More here, http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0405/#id18. I think it's time to update your Python version.

Answer (score 0):

Just install virtualenv via rpm.